# So when I started new project in android studio, where the build output shows "Connection refused: connect"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

and also I can't see my design part of xml code. Kindly let me know what we can do,

I tried:

1. invalidating caches and restarting android studio.
2. build -> clean project -> build -> rebuild project.

[image: Connection refused: connect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I verified that in File > Settings> HTTP proxy, I had checked the "no proxy" option. Then I created an exception in my antivirus for Android Studio and deleted the lines of proxy configuration of my gradle.properties file. Finally, I clicked on Sync Project with gradle files and it worked.